# How to access my app registration details after Lifelog web portal is closed?

Tags: sony-lifelog-api

I developed an android application last year which uses lifelog api but I check recently that I can no longer initialise lifelog within my app and I want to know if there are other ways to see the app registration details such as the client id and secret etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the Lifelog API has been completely shut down at this point and there is no way to access it. We apologize for the inconvenience!